# Partially defrosted chicken in cold water, then defrosted the rest of the way in the fridge

Tags: food-safety, chicken, refrigerator, defrosting

I thought I wanted to cook chicken last night, so I put the frozen chicken breasts (in original packaging) in a bowl of cold water to defrost. After about 30 minutes, I realized that to make the dish I wanted to make, the meat would need an hour to marinate after defrosting, so I decided to wait 24 hours to cook the chicken. I then popped the chicken breasts into the fridge.

My question is: since I started the defrosting process in the bowl of cold water before putting the chicken into the fridge, is the chicken still safe to cook and eat today?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be OK,

You started it frozen and unless the ambient temperature was very warm, the water would still be cold, so the meat was not in the "danger" zone before putting it back in the fridge where it'll continue defrosting slowly.